# Toad for Mysql gives error on Compare

Tags: mysql, toad

I've posted this message on Toad World looking for help but no one has answered.  So I'm trying here.

I repeatedly get the same error while using any of the Compare options when connecting to a remote host.  In this specific case it is a HostGator server.  I did create a support ticket with them, they refereed me to my unanswered Toad World forum post.

The error is:  `Keyword not supported: 'btkkw;pooling'.`

I am using Toad for MySQL 7.5.0.966.  This has been happening for a the past month or more.  I noticed it while running 7.3.x, updating hasn't helped.  Deleted the remote profile but that didn't help either.

Otherwise I can connect to the remote server with no problems, view the db, make changes and export without problems.

Can somebody please help me with this problem?  Maybe make some suggestions?

Comment: I've recently tried again with a newer version of Toad on a different provider with up to date Mariadb.  The same error exists.